# Detecting and fixing a fixed in absolute bug

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a small project, I experience a behaviour in Firefox (both mobile and desktop) that I believe is a bug : using chromium I don't have the bug and inspecting the html triggers a repaint and solves the problem.

In an attempt for a responsive design I have a side panel that is absolutely positionned and slides in and out. In this side panel, I am willing to have a fixed element. The fixed position is only specified for bottom, and the fixed element should therefore translate sideways with the containing panel. In firefox the position is however not updated properly, and the fixed element does not translate lateraly. Searching, I came up with a hacky workaround, but this fix is not perfect, and introduces tiny bugs where other browsers didn't have any. I therefore also desigend a test to check whether the browser experiences the bug, so that I only use the hack when necessary. Here is a minimal example derived from my code.

```js
/* Fix to programatically force fixed element repositionning */
var trigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var child = document.getElementById('child');

function from_and_back(evt) {
  if (container.children.length) {
    container.removeChild(child);
    setTimeout(function() {
      container.appendChild(child);
    }, 300);
  }
}
trigger.addEventListener('mouseenter', from_and_back);
trigger.addEventListener('mouseleave', from_and_back);

/* Simulate the bug to check whether the browser experiences it */
var bug_status = document.getElementById('bug-status');
bug_status.innerText = (function() {
  //create an absolutely positionned element
  var abs = document.createElement('div');
  abs.style.position = 'relative';
  abs.style.left = '0px';

  //create a fixed element to put inside
  var fix = document.createElement('div');
  fix.style.position = 'fixed';

  //insert it into the document
  abs.appendChild(fix);
  document.body.appendChild(abs);

  //test
  fix.getBoundingClientRect(); /************ this line *************/
  abs.style.left = '20px';
  var fix_left = fix.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  var abs_left = abs.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  //remove test elements from the document
  document.body.removeChild(abs);

  //send the result
  return abs_left !== fix_left;
})();
```

```css
/* Wrapper class to trigger the effect */

.trigger {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.trigger:hover .container {
  left: 200px;
}
/* Absolutely positionned element */

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #aaa;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
/* Fixed element inside the absolute one */

.child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #aaa;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Display the bug test result -->
Your browser has the bug : <span id='bug-status'></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="trigger">
  <!-- Demonstrate the error without any fix -->
  <span>Reference</span>
  <br/>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Apply the fix fix -->
<div class="trigger" id="trigger">
  <span>Fixed</span>
  <br/>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="child" id="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the questions :

1. Obviously my workaround is not fully satisfactory : the smooth transition is lost, and in the example, if the mouse moves fastly in and out of the trigger, the fixed element remains dangling in the middle. Do you have ideas for a better workaround, or design with the same behaviour without the bug ?
2. In the javascript test, I marked a line. Removing the line makes the test pass on Firefox. I don't get why, but perhaps this could be used to workaround the bug less roughly ?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround which might give the same result you want is to move the `.child` outside the moving container, and apply the same transformation on trigger:hover, just using `margin-left` or even `transform: translateX(200px)` to not mess with the fixed positioning.

*(Using `transform` instead of positioning on the container actually would solve the rendering issue, but sadly it also makes the position:fixed relative to the transformed element instead of the viewport.)*

```css
/* Wrapper class to trigger the effect */

.trigger {
  width: 220px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.trigger:hover .container {
  left: 200px;
}
.trigger:hover .child {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  background: #aaa;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #aaa;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: all .25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's clever. It is however difficult in my real case to move the child out of the container without breaking the rest of the layout when the side panel is not collapsed on the side on desktop views. I'll give it a try anyway.